# C# Delegate and async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I have the following code:

```
private void LoadImage() {
   (...some irrelevant code...)
   LoadIm = (obj) => {
      var img = new Image();
      img.Source = new StreamImageSource() {
         Stream = (token) => getstream(token)
      };
   };
   (...some other irrelevant code...)
}

private async Task<Stream> getstream(object token) {
   return new MemoryStream(someBytes);
}
```

It works fine but produces an annoying compile time warning: "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread."

What's the proper way to handle it?  The StreamImageSource expects an async, so I can't make getstream() synchronous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proper way to handle it is for `Stream` to expect a `Func<object, Task<stream>>` (or custom equivalent delegate). I'm not sure why your method is `async` at all though since nothing about it is async.

Comment: If `Stream` is already of that form, then perhaps you just want `Stream = getstream`?

Comment: StreamImageSource requires an async.  In other words, I can't just make getstream() to be non-async, I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.IO.Stream>'"

Comment: Why don't you do us all a favour and show us that the delegate signature for `Stream` is so that we can give you a more targeted answer?

Comment: Func<System.Threading.CancellationToken, Task<Stream>> StreamImageSource.Stream {get; set;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to remove `async` from your method and return `Task.FromResult` since you're not actually doing any async work:

```
private Task<Stream> getstream(object token) {
   return Task.FromResult<Stream>(new MemoryStream(someBytes));
}
```

Next you need to call it correctly so that everything works. You can do one of two things:

1. Change the signature of your method to match the delegate and assign it directly:

```cs
private Task<Stream> getstream(object token)
```

becomes

```
private Task<Stream> getstream(CancellationToken token)
```

with the following assignment

```
img.Source = new StreamImageSource() {
    Stream = getstream
};
```

2. Add `async` and `await` to your current code:

```cs
img.Source = new StreamImageSource() {
    Stream = async (token) => await getstream(token)
};
```

Comment: You're right, I've missed your revision.  I've just tried it and it solved the problem. I've marked it accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your getstream method is synchronous and returns an instance of type MemoryStream.

If it should return a Task,
wrap the result to Task with the static method Task.FromResult:

```
private async Task<Stream> getstream(byte[] someBytes) {
   return Task.FromResult<Stream>(new MemoryStream(someBytes));
}
```

The Stream property of the Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource class is of type Func<CancellationToken,Task>.So set it to the delegate like this (I assume that you have previously declared and filled someBytes objects - **edit - completed code**):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public Action<object> LoadIm { get; private set; }

        // ....

        // Declare and fill the someBytes array
        byte[] someBytes = new byte[100];

        private void LoadImage()
        {
            LoadIm = (obj) => {
                var img = new Image();
                img.Source = new StreamImageSource()
                {
                    Stream = (token) => getstream(someBytes)
                };
            };
        }

        private Task<Stream> getstream(byte[] someBytes)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<Stream>(new MemoryStream(someBytes));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: What kind of environment do you work in? In Visual Studio 2019, I compiled the .NET5 class library by adding the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package.

Comment: It would be the same for .NET 5.0 or .NET 6.0. The error is _"CS4016 Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'Stream' rather than 'Task<Stream>'"_

Comment: Here is the Microsoft documentation for the StreamImageSource class: https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.streamimagesource?view=xamarin-forms.

Comment: That's neither here nor there. Your `getstream` method by itself doesn't compile.

Comment: The questioner works with a someBytes array of type byte[] that is filled somewhere before and with a property LoadIm, apparently of type Action<object>, that it must be declared somewere int the "irrelevant code".
Ok, I'm going to edit my answer so that the code can be compiled.

Comment: There. You removed the async keyword and fixed the compiler error.